# Restore Azure Website to initial state

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'd like to "flush" an existing Azure Website (with an application published and running) and return it to its initial state (see sample link below) without loosing any of my configurations, connection strings, etc.

"initial state" sample: http://glenntest123.azurewebsites.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application deployed to another Azure Website and I changed the `Assembly name` of the MVC application.  Let's say the name changed from `Hub2` to `GlennApp`.

When I published to Azure through VS 2013 Community (Update 4) both `Hub2.dll` and `GlennApp.dll` are in the `bin` folder and the errors that are surfacing are as follows:

- ambiguous reference.
- route name must be unique.

My initial research pointed towards `Owin.Startup` auto-discovery.  So i've added the following two lines to the `appsettings`:

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="GlennApp.Startup, GlennApp"/>
```

This doesn't seem to have stopped `Hub2` from being loaded in the AppDomain.

I believe my options are:

- Flush the site and republish, because simply publishing from VS does not remove old DLL
- Try to delete the `Hub2.dll` from the disk with a WebJob?
- Try to add code to the `Startup` or `Global.asax` to seek and destroy.
- Somehow through configuration, block `Hub2` from loading into the AppDomain.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Publish wizard in Visual Studio you can choose to delete all previous files prior to re-publishing. You can use this to redeploy your site, with the renamed DLL and have the old one removed.

If your settings etc. are stored inside the `Web.Config` or in the settings stored in Azure that won't be a problem.

[image: Visual Studio Web Publish wizard]

Comment: that worked.  the Azure Publish dialog looks they had the same options.